# Why Compute Engine SSH access doesn't work with username defined on SSH key creation?

Tags: ssh, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I'm starting work with GCP and currently I'm learn how to work with the Compute Engine.

I've followed the [tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/adding-removing-ssh-keys#createsshkeys) to set up the SSH keys on Compute Engine but an odd thing happens. My Google e-mail is: ascadini.services@gmail.com. At the first time I could access the machine using `gcloud` CLI tool, but I wanted configure the SSH third tool to access that. So, I've created the keys with my username, `ssh-keygen -t rsa -f ~/.ssh/instance-1-trial -C ascadini.services`. This generate a correct SSH file and I've copied to Metadata SSH Keys.

The problem is that connection fail when I try connect use that username.

```
agstcadini@Augustos-MacBook-Air .ssh % ssh -i instance-1-trial ascadini.services@XX.XX
ascadini.services@XX.XX: Permission denied (publickey).
```

And works fine when I've tried use:

```
ssh -i instance-1-trial ascadini_services_gmail_com@XX
```

[image]

I've figured out use `ascadini_services_gmail_com` because when I was connected on machine I've listed the users on `~/home`:

```
ascadini_services_gmail_com@instance-1:/home$ ls
agstcadini  ascadini_services  ascadini_services_gmail_com
```

So I've no idea for what reason the three users were created and the reason the `ascadini.services` username defined on SSH key does not work. Also, why `.` were replaced with `_` on the username folders beneath home folder?

Answer (score 1):

The SSH key pair intrinsically doesn't have any username associated. When the key is created, you define no username. That part after the base64 block in the public key serves just as a comment, to remind you when this particular key was created. It has absolutely no effect on authentication.

You can install this public key it into any SSH server for any user. The user who is able to authenticate with this key pair is defined on actual public key installation, not on the key creation. The server would accept authentication as the user for which you installed the key, not as the user whose name was specified in the key comment (it could be easily there is even no system user with that name on the server).

Usually (on Linux systems using OpenSSH software) it gets installed by appending a line containing a public key to `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`, where `~` is a *home directory* of some user. It is this user who could then authenticate using the corresponding private key.

It just happened the google cloud uses usernames of this form, where dots are replaced with underscores. There is no apparent reason for this; it's just their decision, probably based on some internal knowledge of their system. But in general Unix-based system don't like usernames with dots.

Comment: Why three users were created? Maybe I shot some command to do it?

Comment: Why are you thinking there are three users?

Comment: Because there are three folders beneath the `/home` folder as shown at bottom of the question. Folders: `agstcadini  ascadini_services  ascadini_services_gmail_com`

Comment: This doesn't necessarily mean you have three users. Check owners and permissions on them and also check `getent passwd`. If there really are three user accounts associated with these directories, I think most probably you were created all of them via cloud GUI.